# Flutter Solve: 'Offset is outside the bounds of the DataView' error only on Firebase Hosting

Tags: flutter, firebase, file, dart, web

Code saving file:

```
   on<GeneratePDFFromInvoice>((event, emit) async {
      final aspHeaderLogo =
          await rootBundle.loadString('assets/images/asp_logo.svg');
      final aspFooterSlogan =
          await rootBundle.loadString('assets/images/asp_slogan.svg');
      final fontBold = Font.ttf(
          await rootBundle.load('fonts/Mulish/static/Mulish-Regular.ttf'));
      final regFont = Font.ttf(
          await rootBundle.load('fonts/Mulish/static/Mulish-Bold.ttf'));

      final pw.Document pdf =
          pw.Document(theme: PDFTheme(fontBold, regFont).themeData());

      PDF(
              pdf: pdf,
              invoice: event.invoice,
              aspHeaderLogo: aspHeaderLogo,
              aspFooterSlogan: aspFooterSlogan)
          .createPDF();
      String fileName =
          '${event.invoice.projectNumber}-${event.invoice.invoiceNumber} Invoice.pdf';
      final Uint8List fileData = await pdf.save();
      const String mimeType = 'application/pdf';
      final XFile pdfFile =
          XFile.fromData(fileData, mimeType: mimeType, name: fileName);
      await pdfFile.saveTo(fileName);
    });
```

Error from browser console is:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Offset is outside the bounds of the DataView
    at DataView.getUint32 (<anonymous>)
    at atE.a5A (main.dart.js:92807:5)
    at Object.aJI (main.dart.js:25128:3)
    at HD.U4 (main.dart.js:94596:28)
    at HD.py (main.dart.js:94570:37)
    at anw.$3 (main.dart.js:95329:97)
    at q_.atL (main.dart.js:95196:7)
    at Wp.agb (main.dart.js:95253:8)
    at Wp.cm (main.dart.js:95279:22)
    at Oj.cm (main.dart.js:94447:16)
```

The error occurs regardless of which browser I am on, but only happens when I deploy Firebase. There is no error on localhosting. The error doesn't seem to happen when I don't load a font into the PDF. Also using pdf_package link below.
https://pub.dev/packages/pdf

Comment: Are the fonts being loaded?  Maybe try logging their values or something to be sure that you aren't getting back `null` (or similar).  Possible that the font files aren't being included in the deployment to Firebase Hosting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

await rootBundle.load('assets/fonts/Mulish/static/Mulish-Bold.ttf'));

Simple type was the issue. missing 'assets' directory reference. Thanks to @Greg Fenton

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).